# Sampling rows into different tables based on criteria

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

-I'm sorry that I can't provide any code because I'm at a very early stage of programming in  SQL-

Hi,

my task is best described as follows:

I have 800 applicants of which I want to SELECT the 400 best (Application.Score) of those 400 I want to create 10 groups of 40 applicants. These groups should be diverse in terms of NATIONALITY (Max 20% of same NATIONALITY in the same Group) GENDER (40/60 at least) and Age (grouped as less 28 and more 28).

I thought of using Application.Score as the primary criterion and then somehow fill the groups starting by the highest setting thresholds to th secondary criterions (AGE, GENDER, NATIONALITY). This is so to say that once 20% of one nationality is in a group to no longer accept this nationality and choose the next highest Application.score from a nationality less than 20%. Yet I have no idea how to put this in code... Can you point me in the right direction?

How would you go about this task?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: What if the 400 are not as diverse as you would like?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thx for the advice!

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't formulate my question correctly. Of those 800 I want to choose the best but of those best there shouldn't be more than 20% Canadians/Americans/you name it/ in the final 400 to select. Same counts for Gender, once there are already 200 of one gender selected then take only of other gender sort of... I hope this makes sense to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "nth" sample.  The idea is the following:

- First define the 400 applicants you want.
- Second, enumerate them by nationality, gender, and age.
- Then take an nth sample.

You can do the latter with arithmetic, because you know the total amounts:

```
select t.*,
       (seqnum % 10) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by nationality, gender, age) as seqnum,
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by application_score desc
            fetch first 400 rows only
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for answering my question so quickly! Could you explicate the steps and lables in more detail since I've been introduced to SQL only 3 weeks ago and I have a hard time to decode for myself this language and the labels stackoverflower users use. (for instance what does `t.` in front of * stand for etc.

Comment: @AdamKneitz the t refers to the selected data inside the parenthesis. It is a nested query to select a subset of data. It has been called "t" for reference. The t.* refers to a wildcard or all - may need to help clarify and expand on the second part.